# Quickblox: New chat notification is not working while app is in background

Tags: iphone, quickblox

We are not able to receive new chat push notification while application is in background. We have integrated Quickblox iPhone latest SDK.

If we send notification from Quickblox admin panel then it's working.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

In order to receive push notifications for chat messages you need:
1. Disconnect from chat when going background (chat alerts only working for offline users).
2. Setup chat alerts in admin panel (they must be enabled): http://quickblox.com/developers/Chat#Alerts

I'm also assuming that you have already setup all certificates: http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-messages_users-ios#Creating_APNS_certificates